# Events in Backbone.js

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

Can u help with the click event?? here is my code.

```
$(function() {
            var Trainee = Backbone.Model.extend();

            var TraineeColl = Backbone.Collection.extend({
                model: Trainee,
                url: 'name.json'
            });

            var TraineeView = Backbone.View.extend({
                el: "#area",
                template: _.template($('#areaTemplate').html()),

                render: function() {
                        this.model.each(function(trainee){
                        var areaTemplate = this.template(trainee.toJSON());
                        $(this.el).append(areaTemplate);
                    },this);

                    return this;
                }
            });

            var trainee = new TraineeColl();
            var traineeView = new TraineeView({model: trainee});
            trainee.fetch();
            trainee.bind('reset', function () {
                traineeView.render();
            });

        });
```

my o/p after(trainee.toJSON) is

```
Sinduja 
E808514 
HPS 

Shalini 
E808130 
HBS 

Priya 
E808515 
HSG
```

Everything is fine with the o/p...
Now i want to get this o/p oly after a button click....

Comment: Where is the button on which you want the output to come ? In template ?

Comment: @OP, you may draft your query on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/OnesimusUnbound/vbUK9/) I've provide a template with backbone, underscore included, though you have to find an equivalent for the retrieval of `Trainee` from json file.

Comment: button can be inside the template and wen i click it the o/p shd come in area

Answer (score 0):

Simply add an event to that button. Since you're using jQuery, that should be simple :

```
$(function () {
    $("#your_button_id").on("click", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        // your code here 
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what the o/p is...

Anyway, you can do something like that :

```
trainee.bind('reset', function () {
     $('button').click(function() {
           traineeView.render();
     });
});
```

with the proper jQuery selector $('button') for your button...

Comment: i modified the code like this adding the event....but the button n d o/p gets displayed simultaneously without firing wen th button clicked....in my js code i included... events: {
                    "click #up": "render"
                    }, in html script like... <div class="button1" id="myButtons">
    <button class="first" id="up">
       Go Up
    </button>

Comment: Thanks a lot augustin....it worked for me...after crafting certain changes in my html script